# Crreate table with foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I m trying to create a table in sql, but it gives me an error when I add the foreign key from the table `COURSE`. With the other foreign keys it; Can anybody tell me why.

Here is my query

```
CREATE TABLE ENROLL (
Stu_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
Prog_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Crs_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
Crs_Sec_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Enroll_Outcome CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Stu_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Stu_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT(Stu_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Prog_ID) REFERENCES PROGRAMS(Prog_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Crs_Sec_ID) REFERENCES COURSE_SECTION (Crs_Sec_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Crs_ID) REFERENCES COURSE(Crs_ID));
```

and here's the output

```
Error starting at line : 126 in command -
CREATE TABLE ENROLL (
Stu_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
Prog_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Crs_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
Crs_Sec_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Enroll_Outcome CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Stu_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Stu_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT(Stu_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Prog_ID) REFERENCES PROGRAMS(Prog_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Crs_Sec_ID) REFERENCES COURSE_SECTION (Crs_Sec_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Crs_ID) REFERENCES COURSE(Crs_ID))
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
02267. 00000 -  "column type incompatible with referenced column type"
*Cause:    The datatype of the referencing column is incompatible with the
```

AGAIN, it runs well with all of the other foreign key without the Crs_ID.

Comment: Make sure the CRS_ID field in the COURSE table is of data type NUMBER.

Comment: What is the definition of the `course` table?  Is `crs_id` a `number`?  The error implies that it is not.  Is there any chance that `crs_id` in `course` is defined as a `varchar2` like, apparently `crs_sec_id` is?  As a general matter of sanity, if a column is named `_id`, I'd expect it to be numeric.  If you have a string based identifier, I'd use a different prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is says is Couse ID in Enroll table and  Couse ID in Couse table are incompatible. Both columns should have the same types and properties (not null) in order to make a foreign key relationship.

**Things to check:**

- Are they both have the same Column type (should be Number)?
- Both are not support null?